# Database Design / Examples for Tags

Tags: mongodb

I am planning to create a website which will contain number of documents and each document can be tagged with one or more tags.
I am planning to use mongodb for this. So can you guys suggest me how should I design the backend in mongodb means the database design.

Also could you please suggest any example website which has such kind of functionality that I can use as reference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd highly recommend you read through the Data Modeling documents to get started: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

Answer (score 2):

A very much visible example for this would stackoverflow itself.

It has questions which have many tags.
Example:

```
{_id:123,link:url,subject:'test subject',desction:'test description',tags:[{name:'mongodb',desc:'mongodb'},{name:'groovy',desc:'groovy'}]}
```

Comment: This is a good example. I would also add that in order to make filtering by tags a cheap operation it would be necessary to put an index over the "tags" field.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice...add-on

Comment: Thanks for the response for ID , link and Tags here but is there any sample PHP script which does this?